# What will be the rate of inflation after n months?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I have a utility rate of 0.15 which inflates by 0.5% per year. I then want to convert that annual rate to a monthly rate and determine what the rate would be for month $n$.

The way I'm doing it now (which just feels incorrect) is:
$$\mathrm{utilityRate}\Bigl( (1.0 + \text{rate of inflation})^{n/12}\Bigr)$$

Is this correct, or am I completely off base?

Comment: A rate of $n/12$ compounded monthly gives you a larger rate than $n$ per year.

Comment: The number of months could be anything... in this particular case, I need to know the rate of month `n` where `n = 1...300`

Comment: @Arturo: I though $n$ was the number of months rather than the rate.

Comment: @Hnery; I started the comment before cleaning up the LaTeX, and misinterpreted; then I didn't correct the comment before sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rate of inflation is constant every month then $(1 + \text{annual rate of inflation})^{n/12}$ is indeed what happens to the price level starting at $1$.  So your formula looks sensible.

So in your example with $0.5\%$ annual inflation, this becomes $1.005^{n/12}$. The utilities I know would only change rates once a year if inflation was so low.

Comment: I believe the rate of inflation (being yearly initially) should be divided by 12 in order to get the monthly inflation rate. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @ChrisCashwell:  it will be close, particularly if the inflation rate is low.  The correct monthly rate is as you implied in your question:  $(1.0 + \text{annual rate of inflation})^{1/12}-1$.  To the extent that $(1+\text{monthly rate})^{12}\approx 1+12*\text{monthly rate}$ they will agree.The next term is $6(\text{monthly rate})^2$, so you can see if you think that is big enough to care about.